# Can rendering too many modals cause a problem?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, modal-dialog, modalpopup

I am trying to create a performant and large scale react-redux application. 
The problem is that i have too many buttons that require the same modal to be shown with different content based on which button was pressed and each button has a function that runs whenever their corresponding modal is closed. I have two approaches in mind for this

1) use something like  "withModal HOC" which is just an HOC that renders a modal ( using portals ) inside it and passes controls of that modal to the wrapped component as props. So i can wrap each button with this HOC but i am thinking that this approach can cause performance hits or memory problems if the number of such buttons is very large. Please correct me if i am wrong about this

2) use a single global modal in one page and change its state via redux actions from the buttons. however, then i dont know how to implement the onClose() behaviour of button for the modal because i cant store functions in state. I can use componentDidUpdate to implement this but it would be really hackish.

Any thoughts on this are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your second approach it is very nit and easy to implement.

Let's say you are including this code below at index.js (or at any other top-level component) -

-------------------------------------- index.js

```
    import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'


    ....index...

    const modal = useSelector(state=>state.modal)

    return (

      ...index...

     {modal && (
    <Modal>
      {modal === 'modal1' && <Modal1 />}
      {modal === 'modal2' && <Modal2 />}
    </Modal>

     ...
  )}
```

---

I'm using here {useSelector} react-redux hook, in case you're not familiar, it is kinda the same as mapStateToProps, and  element wrapper that has the "modal-root" id corresponded to public Html file modal div.

Now we should create modalReducer at the store -

-------------------------store/reducers/modalReducer.js

```
import initialState from '../initialState';

export const modalReducer = (state = initialState.modal, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'MODAL1':
        return 'modal1';
    case 'MODAL2':
        return 'modal2';
    case 'CLEAR_MODAL':
        return null
    default:
        return state;
 }
}
```

---

Do notice, both in the reducer and in index I going out of perspective that "modal" is just one of your store reducers, and it composes something like that at rootReducer

-----------------------------rootReducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import ...otherReducers...
import { modalReducer } from './modalReducer/modalReducer';


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   ...otherReducers...
   modal: modalReducer,
 })

export default rootReducer
```

---

Because of that {state.modal} in index refers to this specific reducer, and the reducer gets initialState.modal as begging state (what suppose to be null if you don't want anything to pop up)

Now the last thing we need to do is dispatch actions

------------------------- ~store/modalActions.js

```
export const Modal1 = () => {
return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'MODAL1'
    })
}
}

export const modal2 = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
     dispatch({
        type: 'MODAL2'
    })
}
}

export const clearModal = () => {
 return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'CLEAR_MODAL'
    })
}
```

---

Calling clear dispatch will close your modal. if you want to do something specific on onClose() you can do that with componentWillUnmount() life cycle or useEffect() hook at Modal.js wrapper.
here is some optional coding - https://github.com/YogiHa/Hagai_Harari_17-11-2019/blob/master/src/components/Modal/Modal.js

hope it is helpful :)

Comment: Thank you for the reponse. I know where you are going with this but the problem with this approach is that the behaviour that entails after the modal is closed is encapsulated within the button itself and that behaviour changes depending on the props passed into the button. And i dont see any way that is not an anti-pattern to trigger the onClose() method of the button when its corresponding modal is closed.

Comment: if you need a specific behavior in each modal, why no create each button and it onClick method in every modal JS file?

Comment: Because then that would create as many modals as there are buttons. I want only one modal to render which can change its content based on which button it was triggered by and also pass a callback to it which is a method of the button itself.

Comment: no matter what, this scheme can get you there. think on what you want to change interactivatlly and make it depeanded with operations according to { modal } piece of state in the store.
you can look on the first piece of code where UI addapts co-responend to the store, you can do there basiclly what ever you want